# Maximum mean discrepancy (MMD) custom loss with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, transfer-learning

I am trying to use a customized `maximum mean discrepancy (MMD) loss` to train an `autoencoder` implemented with tensorflow (Tensorflow 2.5.0). My objective is to train the model in order to learn the invariant representations from the source and target data. The defined Gaussian kernel and mmd_loss are as follows:

```
def gaussian_kernel(X, Y, kernel_mul=2.0, kernel_num=5, fix_sigma=None):
    n_samples = tf.shape(X)[0] + tf.shape(Y)[0]
    total = tf.concat([X, Y], axis=0)

    total0 = tf.expand_dims(total, 0)
    total0 = tf.tile(total0, [n_samples, 1, 1])

    total1 = tf.expand_dims(total, 1)
    total1 = tf.tile(total1, [1, n_samples, 1])

    L2_distance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(total0 - total1), axis=-1)

    if fix_sigma:
        bandwidth = fix_sigma
    else:
        bandwidth = tf.reduce_sum(L2_distance) / (tf.cast(n_samples, tf.float32) ** 2 - tf.cast(n_samples, tf.float32))
    bandwidth /= kernel_mul ** (kernel_num // 2)
    bandwidth_list = [bandwidth * (kernel_mul**i) for i in range(kernel_num)]

    kernel_val = [tf.exp(-L2_distance / bandwidth_temp) for bandwidth_temp in bandwidth_list]
    return tf.reduce_sum(kernel_val, axis=0)


def mmd_loss(source_samples, target_samples, kernel='rbf', kernel_mul=2.0, kernel_num=5, fix_sigma=None):
    source_mean = tf.reduce_mean(gaussian_kernel(source_samples, source_samples, kernel_mul, kernel_num, fix_sigma))
    target_mean = tf.reduce_mean(gaussian_kernel(target_samples, target_samples, kernel_mul, kernel_num, fix_sigma))
    cross_mean = tf.reduce_mean(gaussian_kernel(source_samples, target_samples, kernel_mul, kernel_num, fix_sigma))

    loss = source_mean + target_mean - 2 * cross_mean
    return loss
```

Based on this I've created a custom loss function that adds 'mse' loss alongside with the mmd_loss

```
def custom_loss(source_day, target_day):
    def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
        mse_loss = K.mean(K.square(y_true-y_pred))

        mmd_weight = 1.0
        total_loss = mse_loss + mmd_weight * mmd_loss(source_day, target_day)

        return total_loss
    return loss_function
```

This does work when I train the model (where x_prev is the soure and x_now is the target features)

```
auto_encoder.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss=custom_loss(x_prev, x_now))
```

however, if I only use the `mmd_loss` without the `mse_loss`, I get this ValueError:
`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable`